# log4j dont want write to consol and file with system variable in path

Tags: log4j

I have a problem.
Log4j dont want write to console and to file with system variable in path. Only write to file with simple path.
Configuration of my log4j.

```
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
<!--        <param name="file" value="d:/lv-098_JAVA/logs/log.log" /> -->
        <param name="file" value="${LV098_JAVA}/src/main/resources/logs/log.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L:%M)  %c{1}  %m%n" />
        </layout>

     <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="file1" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>    
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: How are you declaring your system variables?  Are you doing something a long the lines of java -DLV098_JAVA= ?

Comment: I declaraited it in Windows System Variables. Thet variable is equals to  "d:\SDevel\lv-098_JAVA".

Answer (score 0):

I found where problem is. It is in Jboss, because jboss have his own logger and it doesn't allow to write to console. You must change configuration of Jboss logger. But I don't know why it does not allow to use system variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring

```
appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"
```

and in root tag you write

```
appender-ref ref="file1"
```

As there is no such `file1`. Due to this log4j is not working for you.